# MySQL - Match two columns to return a value from a Third

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that is using time series data. I am looking to do a year-over-year calculation, but to do that I created two new columns to offset 1 year.

**my columns are:**
date,
value,
intermodal_id,
current_month_code (concat of unique_id and date),
and prev_year_code

I need help making a statement to match the prev_year_code to the current_month_code and return the numerical value (value column) of that row

[image: Image attached of the table structure]

[Here is a simplified version of how I imagine the end result being](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9s4xY.png)

Comment: Do you mean you want to match the `prev_year_code` of one row with the `current_month_code` of another row in the table? How could they ever match if they all have unique ID as part of the code? Please show example of the match you want to make.

Comment: Give us a sample result based on your sample data.

Comment: As Andreas pointed out, there will never be a direct match. However, if you are interested in just matching the month, day, and _`intermodal_id`_, then you could use regular expressions to filter out what you want to ignore and match the rest. I'm not sure how to go about this directly in SQL, but it is very much doable by executing SQL commands in a language such as Python using the appropriate packages (MySQLdb).

Comment: The current_month_code is the primary key and the prev_year_code is a concat function to combine the intermodal_id and a the date minus 1 year --> (concat(B.intermodal_id,'-',(A.date - interval 1 year)) AS `prev_year_code`)

My goal is to have a query that uses the prev_year_code to match that current_month_code (because the strings are the same) and return the appropriate value. It would be a simple vlookup or index match function in excel, but I am fairly new to MySQL so I am having some issues.

Comment: I have found a round-about, and inefficient, way to accomplish this by creating two views.

**View1 - Just pulling in the first two columns of the the table above**
SELECT
   A.current_month_code,
   A.value
FROM table1 A;

**View2 - Joining the two tables to match prev_month_code to current_month_code**
SELECT A.date, A.value, view1.value as prev_year_value
FROM table1 A
LEFT JOIN year ON A.`prev_month_code` = view1.id;

Answer (score 0):

You can use dated for the join to fetch the data for previous year. 
Something like below

```
Select a.date,a.value,a.intermodal_id
From TableA A
Inner Join TableA B ON a.date = datediff(year,-1,b.date)
```